# Add new <input> when the last input within a <ul> has a value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an example set up here: http://jsfiddle.net/t7CKU/

**Here is my jQuery:**

```
var attr_index = 0;
$(document).on("propertychange keypress input paste", ".--variant-val-ul input:last", function (e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (keyCode != 9) {
        $(this).closest('ul').append('<li><i class="icon-li icon-level-up icon-rotate-90 text-light"></i><input type="text" name="options[' + attr_index + '][]" placeholder="Attribute Option"> <a class="grey-link no-underline --remove" title="Remove"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></li>');
    }

});
```

**This is the relevant HTML:**

```
<ul class="icons-ul -li-margin-top-5 --variant-val-ul -v">
  <li>
    <i class="icon-li icon-level-up icon-rotate-90 text-light"></i>
    <input type="text" name="options[2][]" value="Small">
    <a class="grey-link no-underline --remove" title="Remove">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="icon-li icon-level-up icon-rotate-90 text-light"></i>
    <input type="text" name="options[2][]" value="Medium">
    <a class="grey-link no-underline --remove" title="Remove">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="icon-li icon-level-up icon-rotate-90 text-light"></i>
    <input type="text" name="options[2][]" value="Large">
    <a class="grey-link no-underline --remove" title="Remove">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i class="icon-li icon-level-up icon-rotate-90 text-light"></i>
    <input type="text" name="options[2][]" placeholder="Attribute Option">
    <a class="grey-link no-underline --remove" title="Remove">
      <i class="icon-remove"></i>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In the fiddle, you'll notice that a new input only occurs when the last input under size has a value. This should happen for all last inputs in a `<ul>`

Sometime this HTML is generated dynamically via jQuery and when that is done this function works properly. It doesn't work only when the HTML is loaded with the page.

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: Woops! Just edited the question.

Comment: Do you have it enclosed in a `$(document).ready()` handler ?

Comment: @Nelson, `$(document).on()` does not need `ready()` because `document` always exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your selector to this:

```
".--variant-val-ul li:last-child input"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t7CKU/1/

This will select the `input` which is contained in any `li` which is the `last-child` (last `li` in each list).

Comment: Thanks this works, I have to wait another 4 minutes to accept an answer. Just so I can learn is why is it that the `li:last-child` is needed?

Comment: @Xecure Take a look at the jQuery documentation for :last - the reason it doesn't work is because it only selects a SINGLE element, which is the last element of the set you are looking at http://api.jquery.com/last/